# Convert C# HostBuilder pipeline to F# in isolated process Azure function

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, c#-to-f#

The following code is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddSingleton<IHttpResponderService, DefaultHttpResponderService>();
    })
    .Build();
  
await host.RunAsync();
```

What is the F# equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as translating C# to F#, the code would look something like this:

```
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Configuration

let host =
    HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(fun s ->
            s.AddSingleton<IHttpResponderService, DefaultHttpResponderService>()
        )
        .Build()

task {
    do! host.RunAsync()
} |> ignore
```

I'm unfamiliar with Azure Functions, so I don't know if `RunAsync()` should be something that's just ignore or something else. The docs don't make it clear, so I chose to ignore it.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap `RunAsync` in a `task { }`? Couldn't you just `host.RunAsync() |> ignore`?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know how to use Azure Functions anymore after 2-3 massively breaking changes, so I can't say for sure. It's a weird platform that doesn't always work the way you'd expect.

Comment: Using `RunAsync` wrapped in a `task { }` or just using `host.RunAsync() |> ignore` causes "Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated". Using `.Run()` causes no problems. I'll do some more research and post a separate question if necessary.

Comment: Heh, figured there'd be something like that. That's Azure Functions for ya, always with the surprising behavior! `.Run()` is probably fine. `.RunAsync()` in C# isn't special, in the background it's really just doing the equivalent `.GetAwaiter().Wait()`, but compiler-generated.

Comment: @PhillipCarter That's very interesting. How did you figure that out?

Comment: It comes from here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md